# Android apk that tracks fat, muscle, water, and bone percentages

Tags: android, health, tracking

Is there an app for Android  that tracks all of the above plus weight? 
I have a scale that shows these, and I'd like to keep track.
I don't want just BMI. I just a want a place to hold my milestones and monitor my overall health.

Comment: This is the sort of thing for which a normal spreadsheet works quite well. It can be fully customized to whatever you, personally, are wanting to record over whatever time-frame you desire.

Comment: I guess. I just didn't want to have it on paper or an excel sheet on my computer. What's the easiest way to make one on my phone?

Comment: I'd just use a spreadsheet, which can be viewed/edited on your phone using various applications There are some that enable view/edit of Excel sheets. Personally, I like to be able to manipulate/view data *my* way, which isn't, necessarily, what any particular app does. OTOH, I'd be surprised if there weren't various fitness apps which will record some of what you want. However, if you want good recommendations from people on this site, you're going to need to be specific and explicit as to the features that you desire. Your question, as it is now, is quite vague as to your requirements.

Comment: It might help if you could name your scale. I vaguely remember there was some app connecting with specific models. Until then, be welcome to check with my list of [weight loss apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/health_weight); one of them might fit your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, the scale does not have smart connectivity. I am using a spreadsheet as recommended.